# Arithmetic java calculator [SOLUTION FOUND]

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an arithmetic calculator with three numbers and two operators. I want to follow the law as in math, doing /,*,+,- , accordingly. Example of the answer like 7+3*5=22
Done no need help!

```
package first;
import java.util.*;

public class FirstJUnit {

static double input1, input2, input3, result = 0.0;
static String o1, o2;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner calcu = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your number:  ");
    input1 = calcu.nextDouble();
    o1 = calcu.next();
    input2 = calcu.nextDouble();
    o2 = calcu.next();
    input3 = calcu.nextDouble();

        if(o2.equals("/")) {
        input2 = input2/input3;
        }else if(o2.equals("*")) {
        input2 = input2*input3;
        }else if(o2.equals("+")) {
        input2 = input2+input3;
        }else if(o2.equals("-")) {
        input2 = input2-input3;
        }

        if(o1.equals("/")) {
        input1 = input1/input2;
        }else if(o1.equals("*")) {
        input1 = input1*input2;
        }else if(o1.equals("+")) {
        input1 = input1+input2;
        }else if(o1.equals("-")) {
        input1 = input1-input2;
        }

    result += input1;
    System.out.println(result);

}


}
```

Comment: By far the best way to do figure this out is to **debug it** using the debugger built into your IDE; more here: [*How do I debug small programs?*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Using a debugger is **not** an advanced skill; it's one of the very first things any beginner should learn, and then use as the very first thing you turn to.

Comment: You are reading three numbers and two operators, but you overwrite the first operator you read, and you ignore n3 in your calculation. Hence for `7+3*5` you calculate `7*3`. You have to re-think your logic.

Comment: You are overwriting your operation variable so only the * is being taken giving you 7*3=21. Like suggested, debug your code line by line, some rewriting is necessary.

Comment: Try to write various methods, rather than putting everything in the main method. and try to go step by step.

Comment: Separately: Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. Review your course materials, class notes, etc. There will be applicable information there.

Comment: hint: use only one `Scanner`, no need to create more since reading from the same input stream

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `operation` for both the first and second operations. When you read your second operation, you're overwriting the first. You're also only ever performing one operation, not two; but clearly to handle `7+3*5`, you need to perform *two* operations.

If you're going to explicitly handle three numbers and two operations, you need to store the operations separately and handle them separately.

Also beware that the problem you're solving requires that you be aware of the [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics) (BODMAS or PEDMAS or similar depending on where you went to school). `7+3*5` requires that you *first* evaluate the `3*5` part, then the `7+x` part, to get the correct answer. But `7*3+5` requires the opposite.

For instance, if you **only** have to handle three numbers with two operators in-between them (e.g., a **narrowly-focussed** school assignment), you might:

- Collect all the numbers and operators (perhaps `n1`, `op1`, `n2`, `op2`, and `n3`)
- If `op2` has higher precedence than `op1`:

  - Evaluate `n2 op2 n3`, save the result (perhaps `r`), and then do `n1 op1 r`
- Otherwise:

  - Evaluate `n1 op1 n2`, save the result (perhaps `r`), and then do `r op2 n3`
- Show the final result

...but the details will depend on the details of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You have completely failed to implement (a) any evaluation involving the third number `n3`, (b) saving and using the second operator, and most importantly (c) operator precedence. You need to throw this all away and look up the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm, or 'recursive descent expression parsing'.

Answer (score -1):

Your implementation is not correct because you use same variable to save the input

```
Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your operation");
operation = op.next(); // <-- This value is never use, see below

System.out.println("Enter second number");
n2 = scannerObject. nextInt();

Scanner op1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your operation");
operation = op1.next(); // <-- You save this value in same variable operation, the previous value is overwritten

System.out.println("Enter third number");
n3 = scannerObject. nextInt(); // <-- This number is never use after in your code
```

You can use one another variable (like "operation2") to save the second operation and doing something accordingly.

By the way, you need more code to be generic and handle correctly all cases (any number of operators, precedence, ...)